# How run GoogleAppsManager via powershell

Tags: powershell, google-apps

I'm doing a powershell to load a .csv file and execute Google Apps Manager commands.

Code:

```
$list = Import-Csv usuarios.csv
foreach ($entry in $list)
{
    .\gam.exe create user $($entry.emailaddress) firstname $($entry.FirstName) lastname $($entry.LastName) password $($entry.Password)
}
```

And i am getting this Problem:

Google Apps Manager 2.55 jay@ditoweb.com (Jay Lee) Python 2.7.3 32-bit final Windows-XP-5.1.2600-SP3 x86

Usage: gam [OPTIONS]...

Google Apps Manager. Retrieve or set Google Apps domain, user, group and alias settings. Exhaustive list of commands can be found at: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-manager/wiki

Examples: gam info domain gam create user jsmith firstname John lastname Smith password secretpass gam update user jsmith suspended on gam.exe update group announcements add member jsmith ...

I Already searched about it and did not find any reference.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I foud the problem

Correct code:

```
$list = Import-Csv usuarios.csv
foreach ($entry in $list)
{  
   .\gam.exe create user $entry.username firstname $entry.firstname lastname $entry.lastname password $entry.password
}
```

Thank you.